# Expose single parent/multiple child records as one OData entry

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, odata, ado.net-entity-data-model, wcf-data-services

I have a typical parent table/child table setup in which a row in the parent table can have multiple child table associated records by way of a foreign key.  An example:

Parent Table:
ID    Book
1     Chemistry
2     Biology

Child Table:
ID    ParentId    Subject
1     1            Elements
2     1            Periodic Table
3     2            Cells
4     2            Dissections

I have created a view based on inner joining the parent and child table (Parent.Id = Child.ParentId) and have exposed this view to an Entity Data Model as part of a WCF Data Service.  However, when I view the OData feed in my browser, as expected, I see multiple entries repeating the parent information for each associated child entity.

Instead, what I need to do is only show each parent value once with all associated child records in their parent entry.  Example (using pseudo OData)

```
<entry>  
<Book>Chemistry</Book>  
<Subject>Elements</Subject>  
<Subject>Periodic Table</subject>  
</entry>  

<entry>  
<Book>Biology</Book>  
<Subject>Cells</Subject>  
<Subject>Dissections</Subject>  
</entry>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose your two tables as two entity sets with a relationship. So Parent would have a 1 - many relationship to Child table. Then expose that model as WCF Data Service. And then run a query like (assuming the Parent entity set is called Parents and that Parent entity has a navigation property called Children):
/Parents?$expand=Children
This will get you feed of parents where each parent will have an inline feed of its children.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be what I am looking for.  Thanks for your answer.  What about in the case in which my two tables have a many-to-many relationship requiring a lookup table between the two?  I create the assocition from table a to the lookup table and another association from the lookup table to table b.  Is there a way I can expand table b from loading table a in the URI?

Comment: I recogonize I'm asking another question in the comment area and for this I apologize.  It appears though to be a related question so I would think a search on one topic would provide results for both.  Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441665/use-linq-for-double-nested-odata-collection.  Thanks again for your help.